# Create CSV output from Single-Element JSON Array Object Using PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell, api, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

looking for some help.

I'm newbie to powershell and looking to call an API which has JSON output (encapsulated in single array).

Expected Output (couldn't get all columns in excel to show):
[image: Excel Expected]

Below is the response from API:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "Records": "[
                          {
                           'RecordId':'A8E00212-BE7B-4AA8-A87B-121E7018EAE0',
                           'RecordNumber':'1999',
                           'FormName':'Costco Boneless Center Cut Loin (Strap On, Strap Off, Super Trim, Premium)',
                           'FormVersion':'22',
                           'FormType':'Check',
                           'LocationName':'Beardstown (85B)',
                           'ResourceName':'Loins-Costco Boneless CC Loin',
                           'SubmittedUserName':'Maria Nava-Garcia',
                           'SubmittedDate':'2020-11-14T16:54:35.920',
                           'SubmittedDateLocal':'2020-11-14T16:54:35.920',
                           'SubmittedTimeZone':'America/Chicago',
                           'ProcessedDate':'2020-11-14T17:41:23.873',
                           'ModifiedDate':'2020-11-14T16:54:35.920',
                           'FieldGroups': [
                                            { 
                                             'FieldGroupName':'' ,
                                             'Fields': [
                                                        {'Date':'11/14/2020'},
                                                        {'Shift':'1'},
                                                        {'Product Code':'55620'},
                                                        {'Number of Pieces Audited':'8'},
                                                        {'Incorrect Bagging Orientation, S-Shaped Bags':'0'},
                                                        {'Incorrect Pieces in Bag':'0'},
                                                        {'Incorrect Boxing Placement':'0'},
                                                        {'Bag Tails':'0'},
                                                        {'Dating Over Bag Print':'0'},
                                                        {'Bones/Cartilage':'1'},
                                                        {'Number of Leakers':'0'},
                                                        {'Foreign Material/Contamination':'0'},
                                                        {'PSE':'0'},
                                                        {'Incorrect Code Dating and Est. #':'0'},
                                                        {'Blood Splash':'0'},
                                                        {'Dark Bruise':'0'},
                                                        {'Scores':'0'},
                                                        {'Sirloin End Not Square':'0'},
                                                        {'Pin Bone Removal':'0'},
                                                        {'Shoulder End Eye Diameter':'0'},
                                                        {'Gouges':'0'},
                                                        {'Fat':'2'},
                                                        {'Remaining Strap (Strap Off Codes Only)':'0'},
                                                        {'Belly Strap (Strap On Codes Only)':'0'},
                                                        {'Ham Patch Present':'0'},
                                                        {'False Lean Present':'1'},
                                                        {'Tag Ends':'0'},
                                                        {'Packaging Defects Total':'0'},
                                                        {'% Packaging Defects':'0'},
                                                        {'Critical Defects Total':'1'},
                                                        {'% Critical Defects':'12.5'},
                                                        {'Other Defects Total':'3'},
                                                        {'% Other Defects':'37.5'},
                                                        {'Total Defects':'4'},
                                                        {'Audit Acceptable':'No'},
                                                        {'What Did You Do?':'Tagged'},
                                                        {'How Many Boxes?':'15'},
                                                        {'Comments':'Notified Dave Long Hector Rodriguez and Jeff Harris'},]},]}
                        ]"
        }
    ]
}
```

And here's the code I have written so far,

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://abcd.com/api' | ConvertFrom-Json | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data |ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation | Set-Content C:\OUTPUT\OUTPUT.csv
```

The output in excel file is single row record.
[image: Excel]

How can I split it into all the columns in excel file.

Thanks for all the help !!

Comment: Please edit the question to show the expected output and what the actual output (or any error) is. Also please format all code, by selecting it and then press the "code" button above the text input box.

Comment: Replace `Select-Object -ExpandProperty data` with `ForEach-Object { $_.data.Records }`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen , I tried replacing it and output I am getting as Length and 1682 in 2 separate rows).

Comment: @zett42 - Done, any inputs ?

Comment: `Records` value looks like a string that contains another JSON, which is strange. Is this just a copy-paste error or is it supposed to be like this?

Comment: @zett42 - API response is encapsulated in single array and this is how it supposed to return data. Just looking for a way to export to excel file with all columns as shown in expected output screenshot instead of single row of record string. I hope I answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

As `Records` field is another JSON embedded in a string value, you have to parse JSON twice:

```
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://abcd.com/api'

# Parse outer JSON
$json = $response | ConvertFrom-Json 

# Parse embedded JSON
$recJson = $json.data.records | ConvertFrom-Json
```

This is just to get you started. You can't directly convert `$recJson` to CSV because of the nested `FieldGroups` array. You have to process it separately. If you have specific issues with that, it's better asked as a new question.